# how to deleting extra OrderItems in Orders admin panel?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[image]

this is my order admin. when a customer reserve a product it goes to order item section in the down. but there are some extra order items that they are empty. i want to when a customer adds a product just that product be in the admin panel. how i can remove that empty order items???

model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    # products = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='addresses')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.full_name


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.product.name}"
```

serializer:

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    final_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = (
            'id',
            'product',
            'quantity',
            'final_price'
        )

    def get_product(self, obj):
        return ProductSerializer(obj.product).data

    def get_final_price(self, obj):
        return obj.get_final_price()


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'id',
            'order_items',
            'total',
        )

    def get_order_items(self, obj):
        return OrderItemSerializer(obj.products.all(), many=True).data

    def get_total(self, obj):
        return obj.total_price()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `TabularInline` at `admin.py` file not serializers. `extra = 0`

```
class OrderItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrderItem
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OrderItemInline]
```